# two columns reads from one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table VISITS with these Columns

```
Visit_ID , Location_ID , Next_Location_ID
----------
0001     , 101         , 102
0002     , 105         , 102
0003     , 102         , 105
----------
```

and there is a table with Details of Location like Name and another info

```
Location
location_id , Name
----------
101         , US
102         , UK
.
.
.
105         , CA
----------
```

My Question is How to Write SQL Statement to Retrieve these Info

```
Visit_ID , Location_ID , Next_Location_ID
0001     , US          , UK
0002     , CA          , UK
0003     , UK          , CA
```

Comment: JOIN the two tables!

Comment: I Did not understand the trick that i have to join it twice .

Answer (score 1):

Join the `location` table twice:

```
select v.Visit_ID, l1.Name, l2.Name
from VISITS v
join Location l1 on l1.location_id = v.Location_ID 
join Location l2 on l2.location_id = v.Next_Location_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the `visits` table to the `location` table *twice* - once for each foreign key in `visits`, like this:

```
select v.*, a.name location, b.name next_location
from visits v
join location a on a.location_id = v.location_id
join location b on b.location_id = v.next_location_id
```

When you do this, you must use a table *alias* (here I've used "a" and "b") to distinguish the crows from each other in the query.

Comment: @jpw a copy-paste laziness error :( A hazard of  thumbing code into an iPhone. Thx.